# Помогите правильно присвоить функцию

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

```
$('.product__plus:not(.admin)').click(plus_product);
```

Этот код дает кнопке функцию. Но потом есть это:

```
$('#minicart').html(response.fragments['div.widget_shopping_cart_content'])
```

Этот код после AJAX добавляет еще пару кнопок для которых тоже нужно это событие что и для
первой. Заново написать первый код нельзя иначе при нажатии выполняеться несколько раз в зависимости от того сколько раз до этого нажималась.

HELP

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Используй общего родителя и вешай обработчик для этих кнопок на него. Т.е. примени делегирование событий. https://www.jquery.page2page.ru/index.php5/On